# AngularJS showing error on console, when destroy() called

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So i use destroy() to delete items from my $scope.array on click. It works fine, when i open my console the following is showing:

```
$scope.array[index].destroy is not a function
```

so i delete this line of code, in hope it will fix the console error, and it did but after that my app is not working. I checked if it is something else it is NOT it's just this, it is working but the error is still showing. I have no idea maybe because it's an older version?

**EDIT**: Whole function that is called on ng-click:

```
    $scope.SpliceItems = function (index)
    {
            $scope.array.splice(index, 1);
        }
   $scope.DestroyItem = function(index) {

            $scope.array[index].destroy();
        }

    $scope.remove = function(item)
    {
     for (var i = 0; i < $scope.array.length; i++) {
                if ($scope.array[i].Id == item.Id) {     
                   $scope.SpliceItems(i);
                   $scope.DestroyItem(i);

        }
    }
```

**EDIT 2**

So, whats the problem here? I need to dynamically multiply with this function, when adding or removing from array:

```
$scope.getTotal= function() {
        var total = 1;
        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.array.length; i++) {
            total *= $scope.array[i];
        }
        if (total == 1)
            total = 0;
        return total;
    }
```

When i use JUST SPLICE it doesn't change the value of total, it ALWAYS multiplies. When i use splice + destory() it is working fine, but the browser console gives me error for some reason.

Comment: Do you think positing actual code would be useful?

Comment: well, that is the line that generates the console error.. but if you insist

Comment: Note: in case you are using ngRepeat's $index - it's not a good idea. Here's why http://codeutopia.net/blog/2014/11/10/angularjs-best-practices-avoid-using-ng-repeats-index/

Comment: @TanaseButcaru thanks will edit this in my app

Comment: @TanaseButcaru fun fact, im using item, and the index is just in the controller like you can see in the code above

Comment: @Orom I see now, that's good. I though that you were directly calling splice/destroy item fns from template and passing index as an argument.

Comment: @TanaseButcaru wish it was that easy.. :/

Comment: @Orom well, it is. That's what I'm doing in my app. I'm passing the item's id (or any other unique property) and I'm getting its index like this ``var itmIndex = $scope.myArray.map(function(x) { return x.propertyName; }).indexOf(propertyValue);
$scope.array.splice(itmIndex, 1);``

Comment: @TanaseButcaru Well i posted another EDIT, look at it, and you will see my problem :/

Comment: @Orom i don't really know what you're doing with ``getTotal`` fn but you are multiplying a integer with an object and that just returns a "Nan" value. If you change that line into ``total * = i``, then you'll get a value. Here's a plunker with all you're code http://plnkr.co/edit/Wtim4g2qhJ4MNBdLG35e?p=preview - using just splice, and works.

Comment: @Orom ...and also you were starting from 0, and first operation was ``total = 1 * 0`` so total equals 0 and the final result was also 0..

Comment: i have a if which filters that, anyway i think i found the problem, somehow my getTotal is called more then 1 time.. for some reason and it overwrites everything, and thats why it is being multiplied..

Answer (score 2):

Use `splice()` instead of `destroy()` e.g.:
`$scope.array.splice(index, 1);`

Comment: Don't use DestroyItem function - it isn't needed.

Comment: does splice remove the item from the array?

Comment: Yes, it does this - [http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp).

Comment: When i use splice then i have gaps in the list, and the app is useless

Comment: [http://jsfiddle.net/13xk62w5/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/13xk62w5/1/) - there can't be gaps in array after using `splice()`.

Comment: not gaps, but im using array to multiply with a number, so array[i] * someNumber, when i use splice the number stays the same it does not get deletet, the result of the multiplication, with destroy() it does get removed or just divided down. you get my point?

Comment: `$scope.getTotal= function() {
        var total = 1;
        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.array.length; i++) {
            total *= $scope.array[i];
        }
        if (total == 1)
            total = 0;
        return total;
    }`

Comment: Try adding `$scope.$apply();` after `$scope.array.splice(index, 1);`. It happens because Angular doesn't know about your change in array - [http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html](http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html).

Comment: Now it multiplies them, but when i remove item instead of removing it multiplies again on click :/ I do this in a table, if you press 1 table cell it adds the number, if you click another cell it multiplies, if you click in the SAME <tr> it removes the current selected cell and adds the new one you clicked in the <tr>..

Comment: not new Cell, but the number, "onclick(item)", where item is value of the cell, ex. cell.value = 1, on click 1*array[i], like you can see in the function above.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove element from an array try this,

```
$scope.array = ['a', 'b']; 
$scope.array.splice(index,1);
```

Comment: @Orom You should not use `delete` with arrays, never ever. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete#Deleting_array_elements. Check Bananan's answer, this is how you should do it using splice.

Comment: `delete` operator removes object properties. Technically Arrays are objects too with indexes being property keys. However it's important for arrays to have updated `length` too, which `delete` doesn't do. It causes gaps in array.

Comment: @dfsq how do i delete the item, i used splice but it leaves some gaps in my other parts of the app where, like it is not removing them as i wish but with destroy it works..